# Chrome opens list of links in new windows instead of tabs?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm building a custom start page for myself and one issue I'm running into is I want to have a link above all sections that, when clicked, will open all pages in a new tab. I've got it parsing through the list, but only the first link opens in a new tab, all the others open in new windows.

**Here's a link to the page I'm working on:**
https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/114859/code-experiments/start-tab.html

**Here's an HTML snippet of an example section:**

```
<section>
  <h2>Wallpaper Sites (<a href="#">open all</a>)</h2>
  <ul>
    <li><a href="http://wall.alphacoders.com/">Alpha Coders</a></li>
    <li><a href="http://interfacelift.com/">InterfaceLIFT</a></li>
    <li><a href="http://thepaperwall.com/">The Paper Wall</a></li>
  <ul>
</section>
```

**Here's the JavaScript (mostly jQuery):**

```
$( 'h2 a' ).on( 'click', function ( event ) {
  event.preventDefault();
  event.stopPropagation();
  $( this ).parent().next().find( 'a' ).each( function () {
    // console.log( this.href );
    window.open( this.href );
    window.focus();
  });
});
```

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4907843/open-a-url-in-a-new-tab-using-javascript

Comment: That's for a single link, which already works with what I'm doing.

Comment: If you look at the answers to that question, though, the consensus seems to be: "browsers can choose to open a link in a new tab or a new window, and there's very little you (as a javascript programmer) can do about it". Which does seem relevant to this question.

Answer (score 1):

Im not sure if this kind of behavior doesn't depand on your/user's google chrome settings.

Comment: I don't see how, it seems weird that the first would open in a tab but each subsequent one would open in a new window.

Comment: Hello Matus, just as feedback, this is a comment, it is not an answer, consider to use the "add a comment" option in the future.

Comment: Yes, I`m sorry about this, but as far as I know, there is not really an answer :(
but you are right, I should have comment it.